# How to Detect Missing String values for specific groups in a Long-Format Dataset in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, missing-data

I'm working with a long-format dataset in R where I have multiple groups and a column of strings denoting season (fall 2020, winter 2021, summer 2021, fall 2021, etc.). I expect each group to have seasons from fall 2013 to winter 2023. For each group, I need to identify whether any of these strings are missing. The dataset is structured in such a way that each string corresponds to a specific observation, and I want to find out which seasons a specific group is missing.

The dataset looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

#creating reprex df####

#group1
server <-  rep(c("group1", "group2"), each = 11)
#group2
var2 <- c(letters[1:11], letters[1:11])

dataset <- paste(var2, server, sep = "_")

termSeason_year <- rep(c(paste0("Fall_", seq(2013, 2023, 1)), #expected values
paste0("Winter_", seq(2013, 2023, 1)), 
paste0("Summer_", seq(2013, 2023, 1))), each = 10)
    
df <- data.frame(server, var2, dataset, termSeason_year)

#what dataset actually looks like. some groups are missing some season_years.
df <- df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(
        termSeason_year = case_when(
            dataset == "a_group1" & termSeason_year == "Fall_2013" ~ NA,
            dataset == "a_group1" & termSeason_year == "Fall_2017" ~ NA,
            dataset == "a_group1" & termSeason_year == "Summer_2021" ~ NA,
            dataset == "a_group1" & termSeason_year == "Fall_2016" ~ NA,
            dataset == "j_group2" & termSeason_year == "Winter_2015" ~ NA,
            dataset == "j_group2" & termSeason_year == "Summer_2017" ~ NA,
        .default = termSeason_year
    )) %>% 
    drop_na(termSeason_year)

#some are now missing, but won't show up using is.na()
sum(is.na(df["termSeason_year"]))
```

I tried creating two for loops and using ifelse() statements in conjunction with setdiff() to determine whether a particular season was missing or not. Unfortunately, the resulting dataframe does not accurately represent the data. I cannot determine where the bug is.

I suspect there is an easier solution using group_by(), nest(), or summarize()--perhaps using list columns--but don't know where to start. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
# what I tried ##### 
#if not in this vector, is missing because expect seasons as specified here.
expected_termSeason_year_values <- c(paste0("Fall_", seq(2013, 2023, 1)), #expected values
                                         paste0("Winter_", seq(2013, 2023, 1)), 
                                         paste0("Summer_", seq(2013, 2023, 1)))

## Create a dataframe to save to ####
output_rows <- unique(df$dataset)
output_columns <- expected_termSeason_year_values
data_check_df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(output_rows), ncol = length(output_columns))) 
colnames(data_check_df) <- output_columns
data_check_df$dataset <- output_rows

## run analysis ####
#go through cell by cell, check if data is complete, missing, or not implemented
for (term_season in output_columns) {
    #keep track of what season its on.
    print(term_season)
    for (dataset in  output_rows){
        #keep track of what dataset its on.
        print(dataset)
        #unique term seasons for that dataset
        unique_termSeason_year <- unique(subset(df, dataset == dataset, termSeason_year)$termSeason_year)
        #new value to put into cell 
        to_save <- 
            #if in a vector of missing terms, code as missing
            ifelse(term_season %in% setdiff(expected_termSeason_year_values, unique_termSeason_year),
                   "missing",
                   #if in vector of terms that are present, code as complete
                   ifelse(term_season %in% unique_termSeason_year,
                          "complete", 
                          #otherwise,code as not implemented.
                          "not_implemented"))
        #extract the relevant cell, replace it with to_save
        data_check_df[dataset == data_check_df["dataset"], term_season] <- to_save
        #print new result to check
        print(data_check_df[dataset == data_check_df["dataset"], term_season])
    }
}

data_check_df
```

Answer (score 0):

We can look at the number of rows per group, and identify any groups that have less than the maximum number of rows:

```
df |>
  mutate(n_in_dataset = n(), .by = dataset) |>
  filter(n_in_dataset < max(n_in_dataset)) |>
  pull(dataset) |>
  unique()
# [1] "j_group2" "a_group1"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a suggestion! I should have clarified the real dataset has many different lengths for each of the datasets, and that I need to know missingness at the season level. This is nonetheless a great idea.